# Can't extend a layout in Magento 2, reverts to vendor folder

Tags: magento

I have a file called

**/var/www/t_f/vendor/magento/module-reward/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml**

that I am trying to extend to remove a link, so I created

**/var/www/t_f/app/design/frontend/Tf/lion/Magento_Reward/layout/customer_account.xml**

but its still using the vendor folder... any ideas? Not sure what I am doing wrong. Thanks so much!

Comment: Can You put code of layout file?

Answer (score 0):

You Should put your layout xml file to this path

**/var/www/t_f/app/design/frontend/Tf/lion/Magento_Reward/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml**

Answer (score 0):

First clear cache and check.

Alternate you can put the code in default theme folder.

/var/www/t_f/app/design/frontend/Tf/default/Magento_Reward/layout/customer_account.xml